# Undefined function or method 'findjobj' for input arguments of type 'double'. MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, handle, matlab-uitable

I am trying to customize my uitable in MATLAB using java.
However, I need to get the **java handle using findjobj** but I keep getting this error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'findjobj' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Here is my code:

```
     mtable= handles.uitable1;
     jScroll=findjobj(mtable);
     jTable = mtable.getTable;
```

I know that I am passing a number such as:
         handles.dataTable =  3.0205

but that's the same thing I have seen in other posts....I also tried passing the get(handles.uitable1) but it gives me a similar error saying its an struc array...

Please HELP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `which findjobj` in your command window. It will likely return "'findjobj' not found." The function `findjobj` is not a built-in function. It is user-contributed function available on the Mathworks File Exchange: [FindJObj - find java handles of Matlab graphic objects](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects).

Comment: oh wow thank you! I can't believe I did not notice!

Comment: @user3229406: You're welcome. If this solved your problem (at least as asked), please accept this answer. Thank you.